# Looping through HKEY_USERS

Tags: powershell

I have the below code - running this as Administrator it should have access to all HKEY_USERS loaded profiles. However, it fails on looking through on some with the following:

**You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.**

It fails when it tries to get the values contained within the Run registry path:

**$runKeyNames = $runKeySubKey.GetValueNames()**

Any ideas - please note there are test values in Run!

```
$hkeyUsersHIVE = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::Users

$hkeyUsers = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey($hkeyUsersHIVE, $env:COMPUTERNAME)
$hkeyUsersSubkeys = $hkeyUsers.GetSubKeyNames()


$hkeyUsersSubkeys | % {
    "$_"
    $runKey = "$_\software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"       
            $runKeySubKey = $hkeyUsers.OpenSubKey($runKey)
            $runKeyNames = $runKeySubKey.GetValueNames()     
                if ($runKeyNames -match "phrase") 
                {
                    "$ENV:computername -- $("HKEY_USERS:\$_\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run") -- EXISTS-- Key Found: $($runKeyNames -match "phrase")" 
                }else{       
                    "$ENV:computername -- $("HKEY_USERS:\$_\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run") -- DOESN'T EXIST"  
                }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Not all of the user entries under HKEY_USERS have a "Run" key from what I can tell. Try this:

```
$hkeyUsers = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('USERS', $env:COMPUTERNAME)
$hkeyUsersSubkeys = $hkeyUsers.GetSubKeyNames()

$hkeyUsersSubkeys | % {
    "$_"
    $runKey = "$_\software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"       
    $runKeySubKey = $hkeyUsers.OpenSubKey($runKey)
    if ($runKeySubKey) {
        $runKeyNames = $runKeySubKey.GetValueNames()     
        if ($runKeyNames -match "phrase") {
            "$ENV:computername -- $("HKEY_USERS:\$_\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run") -- EXISTS-- Key Found: $($runKeyNames -match "phrase")" 
        }
        else {       
            "$ENV:computername -- $("HKEY_USERS:\$_\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run") -- DOESN'T EXIST"  
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "Skipping $runKey, does not have a Run key"
    }
}
```